# How come my Javascript sequence doesn't work

Tags: javascript

**How come this works:**

```
return str.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase()
```

**but this returns an error:**

```
return str.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z])/).toLowerCase().join('-')
```

**the error is:**

> str.split(/\s+|*|(?=[A-Z])/).toLowerCase is not a function. (In 'str.split(/\s+|*|(?=[A-Z])/).toLowerCase()', 'str.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z])/).toLowerCase' is undefined)

Comment: `split` returns an array. Arrays do not have a `toLowerCase` method.

Comment: It’s a good investment of time to learn how to use a debugger, and how to split up commands like this so you can examine the output of each one.

Comment: is there a reason why switching the position of join() and toLowerCase() suddenly makes the code run

Answer (score 0):

`toLowerCase` method should be called on a `String`. In the first scenario `str.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z])/).join('-')` returns a `String`. So you can call `toLowerCase` after that.

But in the second scenario `str.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z])/)` returns an `array`. You can't call `toLowerCase` method on an `array`. So it will give an error.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still really new at this, please understand if my questions are regarded as 'silly' or plain obvious :)

Comment: You're welcome. Its not a silly question since you are new to JS.

Comment: I was saying that I wasn't sure why it was down voted. I this is the correct answer